# Mobile Toggle Nav and scrollTop

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, scrolltop

G'Day!

I've recently implemented a responsive navigation bar into a single paged site, but I have one small bug I am trying to work out.

## What I'm trying to do

From the Mobile nav, scroll to an anchor on the page.

## What I've done

I'm including the relevant snippets of code.

### HTML

```
<nav id="menu" class="nav" role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<section>
     <h2 id="projects">Latest Work.</h2>
     <p>Content here...</p>
</section>
```

### ScrollTo Anchor JavaScript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Smooth scroll to anchor
        $('nav a').click(function(e) {
            var elementClicked = $(this).attr("href");
            var destination = $(elementClicked).offset().top;

            e.preventDefault();
            $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: destination-15}, 1000);
        });

    });
</script>
```

### Menu JavaScript

```
//  The function to change the class
var changeClass = function (r,className1,className2) {
    var regex = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s+)" + className1 + "(?:\\s+|$)");
    if( regex.test(r.className) ) {
        r.className = r.className.replace(regex,' '+className2+' ');
    }
    else{
        r.className = r.className.replace(new RegExp("(?:^|\\s+)" + className2 + "(?:\\s+|$)"),' '+className1+' ');
    }
    return r.className;
};  

//  Creating our button for smaller screens
var menuElements = document.getElementById('menu');
menuElements.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin','<button type="button" id="menutoggle" class="navtoogle" aria-hidden="true"><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-menu"> </i> Menu</button>');

//  Toggle the class on click to show / hide the menu
document.getElementById('menutoggle').onclick = function() {
    changeClass(this, 'navtoogle active', 'navtoogle');
}

// document click to hide the menu
// http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/08/responsive-retina-ready-menu/comment-page-2/#comment-438918
document.onclick = function(e) {
    var mobileButton = document.getElementById('menutoggle'),
        buttonStyle =  mobileButton.currentStyle ? mobileButton.currentStyle.display : getComputedStyle(mobileButton, null).display;

    if(buttonStyle === 'block' && e.target !== mobileButton && new RegExp(' ' + 'active' + ' ').test(' ' + mobileButton.className + ' ')) {
        changeClass(mobileButton, 'navtoogle active', 'navtoogle');
    }
}
```

## The Result

As I said, the scroll to anchor works beautifully on Desktop and Tablet versions of this navigation (but that is before the JavaScript comes into play). From the Mobile version when I click on a menu item to scroll to, it scrolls past the anchor further down on the page.

I should also mention that when I click a menu item from the mobile nav, the nav collapses and then scrolls, so I am not sure if the problem lies within `var destination = $(elementClicked).offset().top;` being a different value when the nav collapses and therefore scrolling past the anchor?

Comment: please add a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Ended up resolving this myself, the issue was in fact the menu collapsing after a nav item is clicked.

I removed this code and it now works as expected:

```
// document click to hide the menu
// http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/08/responsive-retina-ready-menu/comment-page-2/#comment-438918
document.onclick = function(e) {
    var mobileButton = document.getElementById('menutoggle'),
        buttonStyle =  mobileButton.currentStyle ? mobileButton.currentStyle.display : getComputedStyle(mobileButton, null).display;

    if(buttonStyle === 'block' && e.target !== mobileButton && new RegExp(' ' + 'active' + ' ').test(' ' + mobileButton.className + ' ')) {
        changeClass(mobileButton, 'navtoogle active', 'navtoogle');
    }
}
```